# DB design for Web Services Accessed by Mobile Movie Ticket Purchasing App

Tags: database, mobile, movie, ticket-system

Recently, I was tasked to create a db for a set of web services accessed by mobile movie ticket purchasing app. The basic movie data is almost static, but the session data (A1, A2, A3... theater is showing B, C, D, E... movies at F, G, H, I halls.... at J, K, L, M.... showtime) is to be retrieved from data stored in XML files at a remote server。 The previous design (to be replaced by the newly designed one) retrieve the session data every hour from remote XMLs and overwrite the data in database. This cause problems because while overwriting database, users already connected to the service can get quite different session data than when he first select the movie to purchase ticket. Can someone give me a hand on how to design such a database update process but avoid possible data conflict? Your kind help will be deeply appreciated.